# Cómo encontrar 2 enteros que puedan formar los valores numéricos de una lista y estructurar las respuestas en otra? Mi codigo me da un IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista, matrices

```py
#Dadas las siguientes 2 tablas de ejemplo (siempre ambas tablas tienen las mismas dimensiones)

tabla_ganancias = [[5, 6, 3, 5, 5], 
                   [2, 5, 3, 1, 0], 
                   [2, 4, 0, 1, 1]]

tabla_asignaciones = [[ 140,  220, None,   80,   60], 
                      [None, None,  330, None, None], 
                      [None, None,   30, None,   90]]

tabla_resultado = []
rows = len(tabla_ganancias)
columns = len(tabla_ganancias[0])

#Código que crea result_table y hace la descomposición de las ganancias
#AQUI EL PROBLEMA

#Imprimir los resultados obtenidos
print(tabla_resultado)
for lista in tabla_resultado: print(lista)
```

Descompongo los valores de `tabla_ganancias` que corresponden a las celdas no vacías (es decir, no son None) de `tabla_assignments`, colocando la descomposición de los valores de las ganancias en la última de las filas y en la última de las columnas .

En este caso, los valores de las ganancias se desglosarían (por desglosar me refiero a encontrar 2 enteros que se suman para formar):

El valor de ganancia 5 se convierte en 2 en una fila y 3 en una columna ---> 2 + 3 = 5

El valor de ganancia 6 se convierte en 2 en una fila y 4 en una columna ---> 2 + 4 = 6

El valor de ganancia 5 se convierte en 2 en una fila y 3 en una columna ---> 2 + 3 = 5

El valor de ganancia 5 se convierte en 2 en una fila y 3 en una columna ---> 2 + 3 = 5

El valor de ganancia 3 se convierte en 1 en una fila y 2 en una columna ---> 1 + 2 = 3

El valor de ganancia 0 se convierte en 2 seguidos y -2 en una columna ---> 2 + (-2) = 0

El valor de ganancia 1 se convierte en -2 en una fila y 3 en una columna ---> -2 + 3 = 1

De modo que queda una tabla resultante que tiene en su última fila y en su última columna la descomposición de las ganancias. Nótese que `tabla_resultado` es la `tabla_asignaciones` pero con la fila y columna de las descomposiciones de los beneficios/ganancias

```py
#Los valores descompuestos se almacenarán en la última fila y última columna de tabla_resultado.


#Sistema de ecuaciones que debo resolver para encontrar los valores que necesito para construir la ultima de las filas y la ultima de las columnas de tabla_resultado
# X1 + Y1 = 5
# X2 + Y1 = 6
# X4 + Y1 = 5
# X5 + Y1 = 5
# X3 + Y2 = 3
# X3 + Y3 = 0
# X5 + Y3 = 1

#tabla_resultado = [[ 140,  220, None,   80,   60,    Y1], 
#                   [None, None,  330, None, None,    Y2], 
#                   [None, None,   30, None,   90,    Y3], 
#                   [  X1,   X2,   X3,   X4,   X5,  None]]

tabla_resultado = [[ 140,  220, None,   80,   60,    2], 
                   [None, None,  330, None, None,    1], 
                   [None, None,   30, None,   90,   -2], 
                   [   3,    4,    2,    3,    3, None]]
```

---

Este código no funciona, pero agrego esto

```py
#Dadas las siguientes 2 tablas de ejemplo (siempre ambas tablas tienen las mismas dimensiones)

tabla_ganancias = [[5, 6, 3, 5, 5], 
                   [2, 5, 3, 1, 0], 
                   [2, 4, 0, 1, 1]]

tabla_asignaciones = [[ 140,  220, None,   80,   60], 
                      [None, None,  330, None, None], 
                      [None, None,   30, None,   90]]


tabla_resultado = []
rows = len(tabla_ganancias)
columns = len(tabla_ganancias[0])

for i in range(rows):
    tabla_resultado.append([])
    for j in range(columns):
        if tabla_asignaciones[i][j] is not None:
            value = tabla_ganancias[i][j]
            x = value // 2
            y = value - x
            tabla_resultado[i].append(x)
            if len(tabla_resultado) <= j+rows:
                tabla_resultado.append([None] * (rows+1))
            tabla_resultado[i][j+rows] = y
        else:
            tabla_resultado[i].append(None)

# Imprime los resultados obtenidos
print(tabla_resultado)
for lista in tabla_resultado: print(lista)
```

pero me sale ese error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    tabla_resultado[i][j+rows] = y
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Conviértete en el problema del Sistema de Ecuaciones Lineales
[image]

---

Codigo de preparacion de los datos para resolverlo por numpy como un Sistema Lineal convencional

```py
matriz = [['X5', 'X3', 'X4', 'X1', 'X2', 'Y1', 'Y3', 'Y2', 'B'],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5],
          [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]]


# Obtenemos la primera fila que contiene los títulos de las columnas, y obtenemos las filas de la matriz sin la primera fila de títulos
column_titles, rows = matriz[0], matriz[1:]

# Ordenamos las columnas de acuerdo a los títulos
sorted_columns = sorted(zip(*rows), key=lambda x: [column_titles.index(title) for title in x])

# Creamos la nueva matriz ordenada con los títulos de columnas en la primera fila
new_matrix = [column_titles] + [list(column) for column in zip(*sorted_columns)]


# Imprimimos la nueva matriz
for row in new_matrix: print(row)
```

Matriz ordenada, como deberia quedar:

```py
matriz = [
    ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3', 'B'],
    [   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,   5],
    [   0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,   6],
    [   0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    1,    0,    0,   5],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    1,    0,    0,   5],
    [   0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,   3],
    [   0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1,   0],
    [   0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    1,   1]
]
```

El problema es que da este error:

```py
    sorted_columns = sorted(zip(*rows), key=lambda x: [column_titles.index(title) for title in x])
ValueError: 0 is not in list
```

Comment: deberias hacer `tabla_resultado[i][j]` en vez de `tabla_resultado[i][j+rows]`

Comment: Intente tambien hacer tabla_resultado[i][j] pero siempre me salta un error de indice en alguna de las partes del codigo, realmente estoy algo perdida con este problema porque no consigo que deje de darme errores de indice

Comment: has de ver que linea te da el error. el indice no puede ser mas grande que el tamaño de la table en esta dimension

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Aunque haya mas restricciones que variables y el problema pueda tener varias soluciones yo solo necesito una, que cumpla con que los resultados de las variables X1, X2, X3 X4, X5, Y1, Y2 y Y3 sean todos numeros enteros (es decir, negativos, 0 o positivos pero NO con decimales)

Comment: Ya leí tu pregunta 3 veces y aún no entiendo el enunciado ni la forma de "descomponer" los números ¿Por qué `6` es `2` y `4` y no `3` y `3` o `1` y `5` o cualquier otra combinación? ¿Por qué la tabla resultado tiene esos valores y no otros?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Porque los numeros se descomponen en dos numeros enteros que sumados les  formen, es decir 6 = 2 + 4, no coloco 3 y 3 porque como esto es una tabla la condicion debe compartirse para toda la fila esa, si pones un 3 sera dificil sumar un nro que permita que den los valores en las otras columnas, por eso se arma un sistema de ecuaciones lineales

Comment: Perdón pero tampoco entiendo el comentario. En tu código de ejemplo tienes `x = value // 2` y `y = value - x` esto daría `3` y `3` para el `6` ¿Por qué dices que no pones `3` y `3` en tu comentario pero en el código si lo pones?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Encontre un modo de resolver todo como un sistema de ecuaciones lineales usando numpy, aunque me queda un pequeño error con la ordenacion de las columnas, Agregue al final de la pregunta este fragmento de codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo actual genera una matrix con filas de diferente tamaño. Si bien esta parte del codigo funciona, no estoy seguro si se utiliza en otro lugar donde se espera que haya filas con el mismo numero de elementos

codigo actual funcional:

```
tabla_resultado = []
rows = len(tabla_ganancias) #3
columns = len(tabla_ganancias[0]) #3

for i in range(rows):
    print(f'Tabajando fila {i}')
    tabla_resultado.append([])
    for j in range(columns):
        print(f'Tabajando col {j}')
        if tabla_asignaciones[i][j] is not None:
            value = tabla_ganancias[i][j]
            x = value // 2
            y = value - x
            tabla_resultado[i].append(x)
            if len(tabla_resultado) <= j+rows:
                tabla_resultado.append([None] * (rows+1))
            tabla_resultado[i][j] = y # Parte sugerida por @Sembei Norimaki
        else:
            tabla_resultado[i].append(None)

# Imprime los resultados obtenidos
print(tabla_resultado)
for lista in tabla_resultado: print(lista)
```

Da como resultado:

```
[3, 3, None, 3, 3]
[None, None, 2, None, None, None, 1, None, None]
[None, None, 0, None, 1, None, 0, None, 0]
[None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None]
[]
[]
[None, None, None, None]
```

Las filas 1 y 2 tienen 9 elementos, el resto tienen 5 o estan vacias. Si este es el resultado deseado, entonces el problema es en otra parte del codigo. Pero si no es el resultado deseado. Sospecho que el problema radica en alguna de las siguientes lineas:

```
if len(tabla_resultado) <= j+rows:
                tabla_resultado.append([None] * (rows+1))
            tabla_resultado[i][j] = y # Parte sugerida por @Sembei Norimaki
```

Saludos.

Comment: Ese output es algo extraño porque deberia colocar a la matriz tabla_asignaciones y agregarle una columna al final con las descomposiciones y de la tabla_ganancias y una fila al final con las otras descomposiciones